# C# VMWare PowerCli 6.0 Start-VM from a folder

Tags: c#, vmware, vsphere, powercli

I'm in advance sorry if this question had already been answered, I didn't find anything about it.

I'm working on PowerCLi 6.0 for vSphere 6.

I have all permissions for a specific folder (called "XXXFolder") but not for the whole host.
In this folder I'm trying to automate the Power Off/On operations with C#.

```
VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl myClient = new VimClientImpl();
myClient.Connect("https://" + hostName + ":443/sdk");
myClient.Login(userName, passWord);
NameValueCollection propertyFilter = new NameValueCollection();
propertyFilter.Add("name", "VMName");
VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine myVM = (VirtualMachine)myClient.FindEntityView(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, propertyFilter, null);
```

The powerOff operation works fine this way:

```
myVM.PowerOffVM();
```

But for the PowerOn method, it takes as an argument the host the VM seats on it. So something like :

```
myVM.PowerOn(myVM.Runtime.Host);
```

But because I don't have permissions on the host (only on the specific folder the VM is in I remind), I get out in exception with the following message :

```
"Permission to perform this operation was denied."
```

Note that with the following Powershell command works fine :

```
Start-VM -VM $myVM
```

Does someone know in C#, how to Power On a VM which is located in a specific folder ?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gregu, I resolved the issue. This is the C# code for Powering ON a VM located in a folder. (PowerOnMultiVM_Task doesn't need permissions on whole host)

Please note that in this following code, I removed :

- conditions (to check objects are not empty, and state of VM is powered off),
- error handling (Try/Catch)
- Sync (wait for task)

in order this portion of code to be more understandable.

AGAIN, Thanks to @Gregu

```cs
    // dummy values examples
    string hostName = "10.0.0.20"; 
    string userName = "myUser"; 
    string sFolderName = "myFolderName"; 
    string sMyDataCenter = "myDataCenterName"; 
    string sMyVM = "sMyVMNAme"; 
    
    List<VMware.Vim.ManagedObjectReference> MOF = new List<VMware.Vim.ManagedObjectReference>();
    
    // Create Client Object
    VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl myClient = new VimClientImpl();
    
    // Connect to host
    myClient.Connect("https://" + hostName + ":443/sdk");
    myClient.Login(userName, passWord);
    
    // Create a Folder object which has the name defined
    NameValueCollection propertyFilterFolder = new NameValueCollection();
    propertyFilterFolder.Add("name", sFolderName);
    VMware.Vim.Folder myFolder = (Folder)myClient.FindEntityView(typeof(Folder), null, propertyFilterFolder, null);
    
    // Create a DataCenter object which has the name defined
    NameValueCollection propertyFilterDC = new NameValueCollection();
    propertyFilterDC.Add("name", sMyDataCenter);
    VMware.Vim.Datacenter myDC = (Datacenter)myClient.FindEntityView(typeof(Datacenter), null, propertyFilterDC, null);
    
    // Create a VM object which has the name defined (From the specified folder)
    NameValueCollection propertyFilter = new NameValueCollection();
    propertyFilter.Add("name", sMyVM);
    VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine myVMF = (VirtualMachine)myFolder.Client.FindEntityView(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, propertyFilter, null);
    
    MOF.Add(myVMF.MoRef);
    
    // Calling the Start VM method
    myDC.PowerOnMultiVM_Task(MOF.ToArray(), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @MikaTTC can you try to utilize the
PowerOnMultiVM_Task method coming from the datacenter object?  I reproduced your situation as following:
Made new user.
Granted user a Admin access on a VM folder . I put 1 vm inside the VM folder.

Used API to power it on using:

```
$vm = New-Object VMware.Vim.ManagedObjectReference[] (1)
$vm[0] = New-Object VMware.Vim.ManagedObjectReference
$vm[0].Type = 'VirtualMachine'
$vm[0].Value = 'vm-82'
$DCView = Get-View -Id 'Datacenter-datacenter-2'
$DCView.PowerOnMultiVM_Task($vm, $null)
```

I know this is not c# but i am pretty sure you can figure this out. The method is described here https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc%2Fvim.Datacenter.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I am very grateful. I'm now investigating this way, even if it seems i don't have the reference to the Dll that will allow me to use this method. I will update you here in the next days. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Mika, i am not c# programmer or anything like this, but i tried to find this for you. Have a look . Your c# client: $client = New-Object VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl  , then your datacenter object is : $dc = $client.FindEntityView([VMware.Vim.Datacenter],[VMware.Vim.ManagedObjectReference]'Folder-group-d1', $null,
 $null);    the Folder-group-d1 is the VirtualCenter main tree.  After this you can utilize the above mentioned method poweronmultivm : $dc.PowerOnMultiVM  with definition PowerOnMultiVM(VMware.Vim.ManagedObjectReference[] vm, VMware.Vim.OptionValue[]
option)

Comment: Hi @Gregu , I am very very very grateful. Thanks to I resolved the issue. This method of the DataCenter Object made the operation possible. You put me on the right track and again "Thank you". I share the C# Code for the next people that will have the same problematic. Cheers

Comment: @mikaTTC glad i could help ;) well done with the rest !

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the client and the VM objects, use the following to start up the VM. Normally when powering on the VM, I wait for Tools to be available before moving on.

```
myClient.WaitForTask(myVM.PowerOnVM_Task(myVM.Runtime.Host));
while (true) 
{
    // Get Fresh details of the VM
    VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine myVM = (VirtualMachine)myClient.FindEntityView(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, propertyFilter, null);
    if (!myVM.Guest.ToolsRunningStatus.Equals("guestToolsRunning"))
        Thread.Sleep(2000); // Wait 2 seconds and try again. (Changeable)
    else
        break;

    // Add another statement here that only loops through x amount of times before quiting tools status. 
    // You dont want to be stuck here forever
}
```

you can use the same method when powering off the VMs as well,

```
myClient.WaitForTask(myVM.PowerOffVM_Task());
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this is not relevant to my problematic. I don't have permission on the whole host, only on specific folder in a datacenter.

Comment: Are you even able to power on the VM from web or UI client? I dont think there is any way around the permissions that permit you to power on or power off. You dont need to have permissions on the ESX hosts to power on the system.. as long as you have the permission in vcenter to allow you to power on a system.

Comment: Hi. Yes I am able to power on/off from UI Vsphere client. And even able to powerOff using C# ( for remind, myVM.PowerOffVM(); is working fine, but PowerOn is Using myVM.Runtime.Host as parameter, and I don't have whole permissions on it, so I get out with Exception).